# How to extract ferries from Google maps API using JSON and VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that I use to calculate prices for trips in my logistics business. I have the sheet connected to the Google maps API using this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P2lj4yHNu4&t=886s It works perfectly to pull the distances. Does anyone know how I can use this to pull out the information about ferries? I just want the word "ferry" to show up in a specific cell if there is a ferry on the route I have calculated.

The code I have used for the distance is:

```
Function TRAVELDISTANCE(origin, Destination, apikey)
 
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & Destination & "&key=" & apikey
     
    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpReq
         .Open "GET", strUrl, False
         .Send
    End With
     
    Dim response As String
    response = httpReq.ResponseText
     
    Dim parsed As Dictionary
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    Dim KM As Long
     
    Dim leg As Dictionary
     
    For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
        meters = meters + leg("distance")("value")
    Next leg
       
    TRAVELDISTANCE = meters
 
End Function
```

Comment: This is a vendor specific API question that is maybe not best suited for StackOverflow. Read the documentation and then seek answers in Google specific forums. https://developers.google.com/maps/apis-by-platform

Comment: SEE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Section 4. `Questions asking for customer support with third-party services (such as App Stores) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, please direct your questions to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team.`